# Conditional probability - numered and colored balls from a box

Tags: probability

> A box has four black balls numbered $1,2,3,4$ respectively. The box also
>   has four red balls numbered $1,2,3,4$ respectively. One ball is taken
>   out from the box knowing that it  is not numbered one.  find out the
>   conditional probability that it is of black color.

How to solve this problem? Is it required to use Bayes theorem for this? My approach is given below. Please help and tell me if I am doing this correctly.

> We know that the ball drawn is not numbered one. Hence the ball will
>   be any of the three black balls or any of the three red balls.
>   Therefore, there is a 0.5 probability that it is of black color.
>
> As it is straight forward, no need to use Bayes theorem

Comment: Your argument is correct.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, thanks a lot for your help. I asked this question as I am weak in conditional probability questions , specially when it looks like an application of Bayes theorem.

Comment: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brian noted in a comment, your argument is correct. You don't even need the explicit count; it's enough to note that both the original situation and the additional information are symmetric with respect to black and red, so the probability for black and red must be the same, and thus $\frac12$.